# Greedy algorithm in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples, greedy

I want c in plunder(aList, c) to equal 0.

```
List = [('Gold', 10, 500), ('Silver', 5, 200), ('Diamond', 2, 2000), ('Platinum', 20, 1000)]
aList = sorted(List, key =  lambda x : x[2]) # sort the list above
```

Gives me the sorted list based on the 3rd value of each tuple. So I get:

```
[('Silver', 5, 200), ('Gold', 10, 500), ('Platinum', 20, 1000), ('Diamond', 2, 2000)]
```

I am trying to get the plunder(aList, c) to keep subtracting the middle values of each tuple (2, 20, 10, 5) from c until c = 0.

Here is my code:

```
List = [('Gold', 10, 500), ('Silver', 5, 200), ('Diamond', 2, 2000), ('Platinum', 20, 1000)]
aList = sorted(List, key =  lambda x : x[2]) # sort the list above

def plunder(aList, c):
    aList[-1] = list(aList[-1])
    i = aList[-1]
    r = 0
    if c > 0 and i[1] != 0:
        c -= 1
        i[1] -=1
        r += 1
        return plunder(aList, c-r)
    elif c == 0:
        pass
        print('Done')
    else:
        return plunder(aList[:-1], c-r)

plunder(aList, 10)
```

But when I run it, it prints done and the new list is:

```
[('Silver', 5, 200), ('Gold', 10, 500), ('Platinum', 20, 1000), ['Diamond', 0, 2000]]
```

and also when I type c in the python shell, it tells me that c is not defined. How could I fix these issues?

So if the c value is 10. My expected output would be:

```
[('Silver', 5, 200), ('Gold', 10, 500), ['Platinum', 12, 1000], ['Diamond', 0, 2000]]
```

I subtracted as many diamonds as I could from the 10 (10 - 2 = 8) so 0 diamonds were left. Then I subtracted 8 from 20 platinums and the weight of the platinums changed to 12 (since I took 8 platinums. And now my c ('capacity') is 0. 2 diamonds + 8 platinums = 10 (which was my c).

Comment: Can you please post your expected output? That is, what do you want the list to look like at the end?

Comment: what is the point of `aList[-1] = list(aList[-1]` in line 5 ?

Comment: the point of aList[-1] = list(aList[-1] is to turn the tuple into a list. Since I can change the elements in list but not in a tuple.

Comment: I think that might be your problem.  When you type `aList[-1] = list(aList[-1])` now aList has a list - namely `['Diamond', 2, 2000]` - as its last element.  This should be a tuple.  Correct?

Comment: This looks like the Knapsack problem with weights being replaced by number of articles

Comment: I want it to be a list because I wanna change the second and the third values as I decrease my 'c'.

Comment: And it is a knapsack problem. Should I approach it differently?

Comment: The two statements `c -= 1` and `r += 1` will lead to a wrong answer. In this case, you'll consider one item at a time, but you'll decrease the capacity for next step `c - r` by two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you are relying on Python's pass by reference for lists to modify the list in place. 
That works fine initially, but when you reach

```
plunder(aList[:-1], c-r)
```

Python creates a **copy** of the list and proceeds to modify **that copy**. Thus your original list remains unchanged after Diamonds are exhausted (you hit the `else` part).

Note that you can see this behaviour in your printed `aList` as only last entry is a `list` and all other are tuples.

```
[
 ('Silver', 5, 200), 
 ('Gold', 10, 500), 
 ('Platinum', 20, 1000), 
 ['Diamond', 0, 2000]   #Only list
]
```

If you add a `print alist[-1]` statement to the function, you can see it even more clearly.

```
['Diamond', 2, 2000]
['Diamond', 1, 2000]
['Diamond', 0, 2000]
['Platinum', 20, 1000]
['Platinum', 19, 1000]
['Platinum', 18, 1000]
['Platinum', 17, 1000]
['Platinum', 16, 1000]
['Platinum', 15, 1000]
['Platinum', 14, 1000]
['Platinum', 13, 1000]
['Platinum', 12, 1000]
```

So your algorithm does work but as you have no way of keeping the result, it does not (fully) affect your original list.

Comment: I'd like to add that the function returns nothing from the base case, so the results cannot be accumulated along the call stack.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I think is a more simple approach. Simply iterate through the available treasure and grab as much as you can/need from each one.

```
def demo():
    units_to_plunder = 10
    treasure = new_treasure_pile()
    plundered_units = plunder_units(treasure, units_to_plunder)
    print treasure
    print plundered_units

    units_to_plunder = 1000
    treasure = new_treasure_pile()
    plundered_units = plunder_units(treasure, units_to_plunder)
    print treasure
    print plundered_units



def plunder_units(treasure, total_plunder_units):
    treasure_sorted = list(sorted(treasure, key=lambda t: t[2], reverse=True))
    plundered = list()
    for treasure_type in treasure_sorted:
        # stop condition when desired units taken
        if total_plunder_units <= 0:
            break
        t_units_to_take = min(total_plunder_units, treasure_type[1])
        # update the 3 moving parts
        treasure_type[1] -= t_units_to_take
        plundered.append([treasure_type[0], t_units_to_take, treasure_type[2]])
        total_plunder_units -= t_units_to_take
    return plundered


def new_treasure_pile():
    return [['Gold', 10, 500],
            ['Silver', 5, 200],
            ['Diamond', 2, 2000],
            ['Platinum', 20, 1000]]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    demo()
```

## Output for c=10 (I think as you expect)

```
[['Gold', 10, 500], ['Silver', 5, 200], ['Diamond', 0, 2000], ['Platinum', 12, 1000]]
[['Diamond', 2, 2000], ['Platinum', 8, 1000]]
```

## Output for c=1000 (take it all)

```
[['Gold', 0, 500], ['Silver', 0, 200], ['Diamond', 0, 2000], ['Platinum', 0, 1000]]
[['Diamond', 2, 2000], ['Platinum', 20, 1000], ['Gold', 10, 500], ['Silver', 5, 200]]
```